# iOS 9 Parse update questions

Tags: parse-platform, ios9, libz

I have an app that uses parse and ever since updating to iOS 9 it doesn't pull any data but rather gives me this error message over and over again...

[Error]: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection. (Code: 100, Version: 1.8.2)

I've noticed that libz.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib are in red, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Side note: in a different project I tried to add those frameworks but they no longer exist so I went to add other, then did CMD shift G, then put in  '/usr/lib', and grabbed them from there, the libsqlite3 worked fine but the libz.dylib automatically changed to libz.1.dylib when I added it.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a security exception in your `info.plist` file. Some combination of the keys below should solve it.

[image]

Comment: you might take a good look at other connections your app might be making. it may not be parse

Comment: We have a four square API in another view controller but that doesn't get called until that VC is opened up. It's also https instead of http which I think is necessary for iOS 9. It's a real mystery.

Comment: If you have a proxy app (such as Charles) you can run the traffic from your phone through it and see what other connections are being made.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the App Transport Security requirements specified in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

As a quick fix, you can add the following in your Info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

This code will disable App Transport Security.

Comment: That will work, but it's a bit like swatting a fly with a sledge hammer. Be as precise as you can be when adding the security exceptions. Even my answer above is probably too broad.

Comment: Yeah, you are completely right! When I had to set ATS I started establishing security conditions quite broad and bringing them more specific later since I hadn't no server control.

Answer (score 0):

Your red `dylib` entries are another issue, most likely unrelated to the Transport Security policy error.

Try removing the libraries and relinking to the equivalent `.tbd` files instead.

[image]